# Kivy add widget at the end of layout

Tags: python, kivy

In the [kivy doc](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.add_widget) there is the function `add_widget(widget, index=0, canvas=None)` and we must be able to set an index to position the widget.

> index: int, defaults to 0
>
> Index to insert the widget in the list. Notice that the default of 0 means the widget is inserted at the beginning of the list and will
>   thus appear under the other widgets. For a full discussion on the
>   index and widget hierarchy, please see the Widgets Programming Guide.

So first either index I try nothing change on the widget order. And then i would like to insert my widget at the end of the list and not at the beginning.

If you have some idea :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
self.add_widget(your_widget, len(self.children))
```

If you print self.children you will see the object added at the end of the list and it will reverse the display order on the view.